# Drupal view and exposed filter on different pages

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

Is there a way to show exposed filter and corresponding view on different pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, under *Basic Settings* change "Exposed form in block" from **No** to **Yes**.  It will then be available in the blocks administration page (admin/build/block) for you to add to any region of your theme.  It will be just like any other block, you can choose for it to display only on certain pages, on all pages, to certain roles, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty vague, what exactly are you trying to do?

You generally specify the pages of a view in the View-GUI. On the left side there is a panel where you can can add pages to your view. You can add as many pages as you like.

To show the view as a component of a normal page (node), you could output the view as a block, then specify an area in the pages content, where the block can be placed.